# Javascript Framework to handle popups

Tags: javascript, frameworks, popup

In our (web)project we have some popups (window.open(...)) to display different object details.
There is also some basic communication between the main window and this popups. Now we want to refactor and clean up all this code to make it more stable and extendable. We thought about something like a handling framework at the main page which is responsible to open/reload details when needed, sending messages between windows and so on.

Does anyone know an existing framework for such things and even more important does anyone have any experience with such a framework?

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

The closest i can come to helping you out would have to be http://enyojs.com/, I've actually looked for a solution for window.open but can't seem to find one, so have always ended up creating custom windows, just as you can in enyo.